# Можно ли обращаться к полям viewmodel без livedata?

Tags: android, livedata

В примере документации обращение к полям класса viewmodel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java_1 использовано LiveData MutableLiveData. Можно ли создать обычные геттеры и сеттеры? Насколько рекомендуется  реализация обращения с помощью LiveData и MutableLiveDat?  Показалось - избыточность кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конечно можно, если хотите, ViewModel тут не причем.
LiveData - это совсем другой подход, событийно-ориентированный.
возможно, он кажется избыточным, но он отлично себя показывает и имеет кучу преимуществ.

если же вы не хотите его изучать, либо же он вам не нравится, вы спокойно можете использоваться геттеры/сеттеры.

ViewModel - просто умная часть UI, которая не уничтожается при повороте экрана и куда стоит выносить всю логику UI. а вот как будет реализована логика (геттеры-сеттеры, LiveData, Flow или другие как-нить способы) - дело вкуса